# How to add an attribute to a node in an already existing xml using java

Tags: java, xml, append, nodes

I already have an xml which looks like the below one

```
<school>
  <data>
      <marks name="Peter"/>
      <marks name="John"/>
  </data>
</school>
```

I need to write a java code so that the xml is appended with an entry

```
<marks name="Dave"/>
```

Comment: Read the answer posted here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445828/how-do-i-append-a-node-to-an-existing-xml-file-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append nodes into existing XML File with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240030/append-nodes-into-existing-xml-file-with-java)